# How to properly clear these floated divs?

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I thought I understood the `:after` method of clearfixing with CSS - but I can't seem to get it to work properly. For some reason the `siblingContainer` that comes after the `buttonContainer` containing the floated elements doesn't seem to be clearing?

HTML:

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <div class="action_button">Button 1</div>
    <div class="action_button">Button 2</div>
</div>
<div class="siblingContainer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.action_button {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #f2c059;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttonContainer {
    margin: 5px;
}
.buttonContainer div {
    margin: 0 5px;
    float: right;
}
.buttonContainer div:last-child:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.siblingContainer {
    height: 500px;
    background: gray;
}
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/np0c6feh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also be done by clearing the parent dic rather than the child.

Instead of

```
.buttonContainer div:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Use

```
.buttonContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AgentStephens/np0c6feh/3/

Comment: This is the same as mine, right? Okay, so you are adding clearfix to the last child! Nice.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is the same as your's now but it wasn't when i posted lol

Comment: Okay fine. Sure. `:)`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! Also - I'm accepting this as the answer because while @PraveenKumar did post first his first answer wasn't what I was looking for and he changed it after this one was posted.

Comment: @jessikwa Yeah, that's fine. But I didn't copy. BTW.

Comment: @PraveenKumar No worries - I'm just saying my reason since you pointed out they're the same.